# PostgreSQL average of one column complex grouped by other (date) column

Tags: postgresql, date, group-by, average

Here is the simplified version of my database table.

| id | firstregistration | km |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-03-24 | 234 |
| 2 | 2019-10-08 | 3456 |
| 3 | 2020-02-07 | 2454 |
| 4 | 2019-11-28 | 7686 |
| 5 | 2019-01-18 | 4564 |

The table contains car data such as: first registration date, mileage, price, car model...

My goal is to structure query to get analytics metrics from this DB table. My end goal should look like this:

[image]

I would need to use firstregistration dates to construct age groups, based on which I would pull other data.

Currently I have solved first and second column. And the SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration))<1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0-1",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "1-2",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "2-3",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "3-4",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "4-5",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "5-6",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "6-7",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "7-8",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "8-9",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) BETWEEN 8 AND 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "9-10",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ">=10" FROM car_table
```

For this I get the output that looks like this:

[image]

This result is totally fine and it solves the first two columns of the graph on the first image. Now I am having trouble adding average km data by these groups.

Does anyone know how to achieve it painlessly?
One important thing to add that the average KM query doesn't need to be part of my first query. Making this an additional query is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get result just in one  query.

```sql
SELECT  age , COUNT(age) as NroCars , AVG(km) , AVG(price) FROM (
     SELECT  date_part('year', age(firstregistration)) as age,
             km ,
             price
     FROM TABLE 
) temp_table
GROUP BY age
```

Comment: It isn't exactly what I wanted. But it did help me, to construct it. Thanks